# innobackupex: What causes Slave_open_temp_tables did not become zero after waiting 15 minutes?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, percona-tools

As you might know, in order to assure a consistent replication state, the slave should be backup only when there are no open temporary tables:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-features-temptables.html
- http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/replication_ibk.html

What I am getting is:

```
innobackupex:: Slave open temp tables: 10
innobackupex:: Starting slave SQL thread, waiting 3 seconds, then checking Slave_open_temp_tables again (299 attempts remaining)..
.
>> log scanned up to (543379918280)
>> log scanned up to (543382186733)
innobackupex:: Slave open temp tables: 13
innobackupex:: Starting slave SQL thread, waiting 3 seconds, then checking Slave_open_temp_tables again (298 attempts remaining)...
>> log scanned up to (543383410142)
>> log scanned up to (543384217254)
innobackupex:: Slave open temp tables: 16
innobackupex:: Starting slave SQL thread, waiting 3 seconds, then checking Slave_open_temp_tables again (297 attempts remaining)..
...

innobackupex:: Starting slave SQL thread, waiting 3 seconds, then checking Slave_open_temp_tables again (1 attempts remaining)...
>> log scanned up to (543458889721)
>> log scanned up to (543459141720)
innobackupex:: Slave open temp tables: 16
innobackupex:: Starting slave SQL thread, waiting 3 seconds, then checking Slave_open_temp_tables again (0 attempts remaining)...
>> log scanned up to (543459141720)
innobackupex:: Slave open temp tables: 16
innobackupex: Error: Slave_open_temp_tables did not become zero after waiting 900 seconds at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 379.
```

So the question is:

1. what cause the slave SQL thread keeps openning the temporary tables?
   Long running transaction, ...?
2. Is there any way to know what the MySQL is doing with temporary
   tables?